# JavaScript- let showing name instead of value

Tags: javascript, variables, let

I am a beginner and Started learning JavaScript today. I tried from a tutorial:

let a = 1
console.log('a')

Now,when I run it, the answer should be the value which is 1, but it shows me the name instead which is a.

What I am doing wrong?? I am using VsCode and console from chrome to see the results..

I tried:

let a = 1
console.log('a')

Google console shows me a instead of 1.

Comment: Typo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#string_literals

Comment: what does `console.log("'a' is a string not a variable")` output

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you do,
`let a = 1;`

It creates a variable (named a) that is holding the value **1**.

Now, in order to **access the value** stored in a, you must do:

`console.log(a)`

You are doing `console.log('a')`

The above statement prints out the character 'a' onto the console.
Because whatever inside the console.log() is a string, and strings are directly logged onto the console.

You can fix this by writing:

`console.log(a);` Its output will be 1, because you have stored 1 in a.